# Which is the easiest/best way to have multiple pins/locations on your mapview?

Tags: iphone, xcode, loops, dictionary, xcode4.5

I'm trying to make an app that has multiple pins/locations (about 50-100). Which way is the easiest way to go? Can I have some sort of database where I get my locations from?
At the moment I have a code that works great, but It only shows one location/pin. How do I add more on the current code? Or as I said earlier, is it any other easier way with some sort of database?

Here's the code:
SecoundViewController.h :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController {

MKMapView *mapview;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapview;

-(IBAction)setMap:(id)sender;

-(IBAction)getlocation;

@end
```

SecoundViewController.m :

```
#import "SecondViewController.h"
#import "NewClass.h"

@interface SecondViewController ()

@end

@implementation SecondViewController

@synthesize mapview;

-(IBAction)getlocation {

mapview.showsUserLocation = YES;

}

-(IBAction)setMap:(id)sender {

switch (((UISegmentedControl *) sender).selectedSegmentIndex) {

    case 0:

        mapview.mapType = MKMapTypeStandard;

        break;

    case 1:

        mapview.mapType = MKMapTypeSatellite;

        break;

    case 2:

        mapview.mapType = MKMapTypeHybrid;

        break;

    default:

        break;

}

}

-(void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

[mapview setMapType:MKMapTypeStandard];
[mapview setZoomEnabled:YES];
[mapview setScrollEnabled:YES];

MKCoordinateRegion region = { {0.0, 0.0 }, {0.0, 0.0 } };
region.center.latitude = 56.15881;
region.center.longitude = 13.76454;
region.span.longitudeDelta = 0.01f;
region.span.latitudeDelta = 0.01f;
[mapview setRegion:region animated:YES];

NewClass *ann = [[NewClass alloc] init];
ann.title = @"Harrys Pub & Restaurang";
ann.subtitle = @"Järnvägsgatan 7";
ann.coordinate = region.center;
[mapview addAnnotation:ann];

}

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all depends how you plan to enter and maintain info about the pins.
You can use XML, JSON, plist, CoreData...

Comment: Where can I find a tutorial for CoreData? I've searched like crazy and didn't find anything that had anything with pins at mapview in it. Or do I need to learn everything about coredata to understand be able to fix it? Also cheers for the response! Really helpful! :)

Comment: Try this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/3903094/619434, there are some tutorials. Once you figure how to read and write data with CoreData, adding the pins will be easy one!

Comment: Looks like great tutorials, though I don't want people using the app to be able to add any pins (locations) I want the pins to pop up at the map when you open it and show adresses. I scrolled through the tutorial and it seemed like you can add data to your database? Or that doesn't matter, I only need to understand how it works?

Comment: It's up to you whether you'll allow app users to enter their own data or not. You'll have to add data at least once :)

Comment: Okay! Thanks alot Alex! Very much appreciated! :D

Answer (score 0):

You can populate an `NSArray` of `NewClass` objects and call:

`[mapview addAnnotations:arrayOfAnnotations];` //(note the final 's' in the method)

to put all the annotations on the mapview.
 Obvisouly each annotation should have different coordinates.

For storing the coordinates as @Alex said you can choose the format you prefer.